# How columns are hashed when sharding in YugabyteDB YSQL

Tags: yugabytedb

[Question posted by a user on [YugabyteDB Community Slack](https://www.yugabyte.com/slack)]

In YSQL, If my table is using the primary key defined on multiple columns then what will be the sharding key in this case? Will both columns be used to compute the hash? Also, can we specify columns to be used as partition/sharding keys without mentioning them in primary keys? What if one of the tables does not have primary keys but needs to be sharded on one of the columns?

Answer (score 0):

By default when multiple columns are configured in a primary key, the first column is hashed, and additional columns are ordered by ascending range.
But you have full control over the primary key definition, which means that you can specify it in any way you like: https://docs.yugabyte.com/latest/api/ysql/the-sql-language/statements/ddl_create_table/#primary-key

Currently, you can only shard with columns that are in the PRIMARY KEY. If a table doesn’t have a primary key, an implicit one gets created internally and the table is sharded based on that. Thus, it is a best practice to always create a primary key.